# GitHub relative internal repository links in PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md

Tags: github, markdown, relative-path, readme

Using a relative link as directed (https://help.github.com/articles/about-readmes/#relative-links-and-image-paths-in-readme-files) in a PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md does not relatively link correctly.

When viewed in an actual PR:

- `[CONTRIBUTING.md](/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md)`

routes to: `https://github.com/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md`.

- `[CONTRIBUTING.md](.github/CONTRIBUTING.md)`
- `[CONTRIBUTING.md](./.github/CONTRIBUTING.md)`

route to:
`https://github.com/owner/repo/compare/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md`

instead of `https://github.com/owner/repo/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md`.

Changing to `../` to go up a level would work for PRs, but would break the link when viewed in the GitHub UI.

Clicking the link as viewed on GitHub works: https://github.com/fs-webdev/fs-dialog/blob/master/.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md, just not inside a PR.

(I feel like this used to work in 2017)

What is the correct way to have the relative link function as expected in both cases?

Comment: Relative links never start with a `/`. Try removing the `/` at the start of the link. In fact the linked documentation suggests `./` (the dot is before the slash not after) while you have `/.`

Comment: Removing the leading slash or adding a dot before it results in a GitHub comparison link: 
`https://github.com/owner/repo/compare/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md`, since that is the route a PR originates from.

Comment: I suspect you either need to do `github/CONTRIBUTING.md` or `./github/CONTRIBUTING.md`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Background

Unfortunately, the given implementation seems to consider only the **current
URL** instead of the **actual file path** in the repository.

The same limitation can be noted when **creating issues** (through e.g.:
`https://github.com/owner/repo/issues/new`):

`[CONTRIBUTING.md](.github/CONTRIBUTING.md)`

->

`https://github.com/owner/repo/issues/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md`

#### Workaround

I only managed to make the relative link work by specifying the full **URL
path** (including the leading `/`):

`[CONTRIBUTING.md](/owner/repo/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md)`

->

`https://github.com/owner/repo/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md`

With that said, the abstraction can only go up to the **URL host** (i.e.:
`https://github.com`).